# Android app with React Native dynamic using a RootView in a layout and the JS using the navigator

Tags: android, react-native

There is a error that    Exception in native call from JS                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference   !!

I just add the rootView in a linearLayout,like this:

```js
  linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.apps_detail_for_react_liear);
        back.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        reactRootView = getReactRootView();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("indentifer",reactApp.detail_regist_identify);
        bundle.putString("version",reactApp.last_version);
        reactInstanceManager = ReactUtil.getReactInstanceManager(getApplication(),reactApp.jsFilePath,reactApp.jsFilePath,"index.android",getPackages());
        reactRootView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager,reactApp.detail_regist_identify,bundle);

        linearLayout.addView(reactRootView);
```

```
       the first running is ok, I have a button in my first JS,and its function is to add another page,just like this :
```

```js
  const { navigator } = this.props;
      if(navigator) {
        navigator.push({
          name: 'VentilationSetting',
          component: VentilationSetting,
          params: {
            height: _height,
          }
        })
      }
```

Then the error happen.

Is there something that I missed？  How should I do it?